# Swagger Docs UI - is it possible to replace Add Integer Item button with input form

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

**openapi.yaml**

```
parameters:
    - name: competitionIds
      in: query
      description: >-
          Unique identifier for the competition.
      required: true
      schema:
          type: array
          items:
              type: integer
```

here is the parameter in our docs, and here is how it looks in the swagger docs:

[image]

and only when we click on the button, the input field appears:

[image]

I believe the UI for our docs would be a bit better without the `Add Integer Item` buttons entirely. When a user clicks `Try it out` on a route, all of the integer item input forms should automatically be showing, starting as empty. Is this possible?